# How do I add values in an array when there is a null entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, statistics, time-series

I want to create a real time-series array.  Currently, I am using the statistics gem to pull out values for each 'day':

```
define_statistic :sent_count, :count
=> :all, :group => 'DATE(date_sent)',    
:filter_on => {:email_id => 'email_id
> = ?'}, :order => 'DATE(date_sent) ASC'
```

What this does is create an array where there are values for a date, for example

```
[["12-20-2010",1], ["12-24-2010",3]]
```

But I need it to fill in the null values, so it looks more like:

```
[["12-20-2010",1], ["12-21-2010",0], ["12-22-2010",0], ["12-23-2010",0], ["12-24-2010",3]]
```

Notice how the second example has "0" values for the days that were missing from the first array.

Comment: This sounds like a question for the statistics gem; could you link to more details on it?

Comment: I thought this could be handled with some ruby array function to fill in the null values, but here is the link: https://github.com/acatighera/statistics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'date'
require 'pp'

def add_missing_dates(series)
  series.map do |date, value|
    [Date.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y'), value]
  end.inject([]) do |series, date_and_value|
    filler = if series.empty?
               []
             else
               ((series.last[0]+ 1)..(date_and_value[0] - 1)).map do |date|
                 [date, 0]
               end
             end
    series + filler + [date_and_value]
  end.map do |date, value|
    [date.to_s, value]
  end
end

a = [["12-20-2010",1], ["12-24-2010",3]]
pp add_missing_dates(a)
# => [["2010-12-20", 1],
# =>  ["2010-12-21", 0],
# =>  ["2010-12-22", 0],
# =>  ["2010-12-23", 0],
# =>  ["2010-12-24", 3]]
```

I would recommend against monkey-patching the base classes to include this method: It's not all that general purpose; even if it were, it just doesn't need to be there.  I'd stick it in a module that you can mix in to whatever code needs it:

```
module AddMissingDates
  def add_missing_dates(series)
    ...
  end
end

class MyClass
  include AddMissingDates
  ...
end
```

However, if you really want to:

```
def Array.add_missing_dates(series)
  ...
end
```

Comment: right, yes, I'd like to do it as a module, so I would store it in the lib/ directory as add_missing_dates.rb?

Comment: I see...thank you...I did a google search on 'pp' to understand a little better what is doing, but I coudln't find it.  What is 'pp'? :)

Comment: @Angela, It's like p, the standard way to inspect an object to stdout, but makes prettier output (pp stands for "pretty print," I think).  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/files/lib/pp_rb.html

Comment: @wayne, thanks, sorry to be so slow with your elegant solution, I got lost at series + filler + [date_and_value].  It seems that series should represent the original values converted to date and you used inject to go to the in-between and add the filler of date,0.  But what is date_and_value then?  Thanks...sorry, trying to understand as I implement.... :\

Comment: @wayne -- hi, I am getting an invalid date error, not sure how to go about debugging it since I'm not getting more information, it is around the strptime line

Comment: @wayne -- hehe, I fixed the invalidate date error :) it works, just trying to understand it better...

Comment: @Angela, No worries.  To unravel the mystery of `inject`, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710501/need-a-simple-explanation-of-the-inject-method.  The key to reading the `series + filler...` line is that `series` is the new series *so far*.

Comment: i think I see now...[date_and_value] contain the remaining set of date-value keypairs that are remaining....I think...

Comment: @Angela, almost.  `date_and_value` contains a single date/value pair.  `inject` calls its block once for each date/value pair, passing in the accumulated output (`series`) as and the date_value pair (`date_and_value`).  The result of the block becomes the new accumulated output.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pp'
require 'date'

# convert the MM-DD-YYYY format date string to a Date
DATE_FORMAT = '%m-%d-%Y'
def parse_date(s)
  Date.strptime(s, DATE_FORMAT)
end

dates = [["12-20-2010",1], ["12-24-2010",3]]

# build a hash of the known dates so we can skip the ones that already exist.
date_hash = Hash[*dates.map{ |i| [parse_date(i[0]), i[-1]] }.flatten]

start_date_range = parse_date(dates[0].first) 
end_date_range   = parse_date(dates[-1].first)

# loop over the date range...
start_date_range.upto(end_date_range) do |d|
  # ...and adding entries for the missing ones.
  date_hash[d] = 0 if (!date_hash.has_key?(d))
end

# convert the hash back into an array with all dates
all_dates = date_hash.keys.sort.map{ |d| [d.strftime(DATE_FORMAT), date_hash[d] ] }
pp all_dates

# >> [["12-20-2010", 1],
# >>  ["12-21-2010", 0],
# >>  ["12-22-2010", 0],
# >>  ["12-23-2010", 0],
# >>  ["12-24-2010", 3]]
```

Most of the code is preparing things, either to build a new array, or return the date objects back to strings.

Comment: cool, how would you suggest I create it?  Is it possible it could be a library, so that I could take the original array and run a method on it?  such as dates.convert_to_timeseries ?