# Displaying data using Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I have data that is daily added by the user via a form.  A few of these fields record temperature: :ambcur, :ambmin, :ambmax etc
this is all part of a tray which has a datalog

I am using chartkick and its great but I am unsure how to display the data over time.

Im trying to do a multiseries linechart.

```
<%= line_chart [
                 {name: "Series A", data: @tray.datalogs.ambcur},
                 {name: "Series B", data: @tray.datalogs.ambmin}
             ] %>
```

Also, a singular linechart does not work either.

```
<%= line_chart @tray.datalogs.group(:ambcur).count %>
```

Can someone help steer me in the right direction?  thanks :)

Comment: do you have **groupdate** gem installed ?

Comment: @RareFever no I have it commented out because it doesnt work with my dev database, but works in pg.  So the recommendation was to use dataslices.

Comment: can you render the example called "Timeline" ? dataslices is a gem ? , if yes, leave a link pls.

Comment: @RareFever My bad, its called Dateslices and yes its a gem made by the same people who made Chartkick.  And yes I can render the timeline example.  I just need to know how to render the data from my form.  https://github.com/HappyFunCorp/dateslices

Comment: That does not work either.  it still shows no line, just the axis

Comment: let me know if it works. In case it does, dont forget to vote +1 for the answer. Happy coding !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you were not passing the correct data format to the `line_chart`. To draw an line chart the data must be in format of an Hash, like this:

```
<%= line_chart {"2016-05-21 23:50:40 UTC"=>20, "2016-05-21 23:50:57  TC"=>23} %>
```

**{"2016-05-21 23:50:40 UTC"=>20, "2016-05-21 23:50:57 UTC"=>23}**

In previous example you see dates (strings) as the keys to the hash and the values (integers) are 20 and 23.
In your case you need an Hash where the keys are the dates and values of the Hash are the max,min or current temperature. **{ "date_1" => number, "date_2" => number, ... }**

To test my code I created a model called **Temperature**. Here is the table:

```
  create_table "temperatures", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "max",        limit: 4
    t.integer  "min",        limit: 4
    t.integer  "current",    limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
  end
```

In my view I called this:

```
<%= line_chart [
 {name: "Series A", data: Temperature.all.inject({}) {|res, v| res[v[:created_at]] = v.max; res }},
 {name: "Series B", data: Temperature.all.inject({}) {|res, v| res[v[:created_at]] = v.current; res }},
 {name: "Series C", data: Temperature.all.inject({}) {|res, v| res[v[:created_at]] = v.min; res }}
             ] %>
```

And I got the plot with 3 lines showing max,min and current temperature over time.

[image]

I used `inject` method to create an Hash where keys are dates and values are the attributes [max,min, current] of model **Temeperature**. For additional information on **inject** method, read [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710501/need-a-simple-explanation-of-the-inject-method).

In your case you should try this:

```
<%= line_chart [
 {name: "Series A", data: @tray.datalogs.inject({}) {|res, v| res[v[:created_at]] = v.ambmax; res }},
 {name: "Series B", data: @tray.datalogs.inject({}) {|res, v| res[v[:created_at]] = v.ambcur; res }},
 {name: "Series C", data: @tray.datalogs.inject({}) {|res, v| res[v[:created_at]] = v.ambmin; res }}
                 ] %>
```

Comment: Thanks, ill give this a shot.