# How to convert 3.2K and 5.6M values in CSV to integers in Ruby and add them

Tags: ruby, csv, syntax, spreadsheet, data-analysis

How do I convert 1.23M and 7.89K values into regular integers and add all values in `:damage_property` and `:damage_crops`?

In pseudocode it would be:

- identify values with "K", remove "K" from end of string, convert string to float, multiply by 1000
- identify values with "M", remove "M" from end of string, convert string to float, multiply by 1000000
- ignore blank values, include all other values
- add together all values in categories `:damage_property` and `:damage_crops`

I wrote some code but it isn't working:

```
kdata_property = states.select do |element| 
  element[:damage_property]
   if element.includes?"K"
     remove "K"
     element.to_f
     element*1000
   end
  end
```

The idea was to then do kdata_crops, mdata_property, mdata_crops, plaindata, and add it all. Can anyone help, please? I think I am doing something wrong with `.includes`.

Comment: if you include active support, you can use `String#ends_with?` instead of `String#includes`, but that's not a failsafe solution. It really depends on how normalized this data is. Are you certain that all the `states` are strings of this specific format?

Comment: Current [Ruby v2.3.1 includes `ends_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F) so adding ActiveSupport isn't necessary.

Comment: Rather than pseudocode, we'd like to see your actual attempt. We appreciate that coding isn't easy, but we want to see that you put in the effort and didn't bail early hoping we'd write it for you. See "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" which talks about this. When asking about code you've written we need the minimum input data to demonstrate the code and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below. I changed `states.select` to `states.map`. I think this is what you want.

```
kdata_property = states.map do |element|
  # This line will remove leading and trailing whitespace characters
  value = element[:damage_property].nil? ? "" : element[:damage_property].strip

  # Check if last character is k or K
  if value[-1] == "K" || value[-1] == "k"
    # Take substring without last character
    value[0..-2].to_f * 1000
  elsif value[-1] == "M" || value[-1] == "m"
    value[0..-2].to_f * 1000000
  else
    nil
  end
end

# This will sum all values
kdata_property.compact.inject(0) { |sum, value| sum + value }
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! That seems like a great way to do it, but I am getting an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Great, thank you! I am not sure I understand the summing part or the .nil? ? "", but it does work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710501/need-a-simple-explanation-of-the-inject-method if you want to understand inject. nil? ? ... is just a shortcut for if else block. If damage_property is nil value will be "" if it is not nil it will strip spaces from it

Comment: @lenchok You can approve an answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with something like:

```
[
  ' 12345.67890 ',
  '3.14159',
  '7.89K',
  '1.23M',
  '3.141B',
].map{ |v|
  multiplier = case v.strip[/.$/].upcase
              when 'K'
                1_000
              when 'M'
                1_000_000
              when 'B'
                1_000_000_000
              else
                1
              end
  v.to_f * multiplier
}
# => [12345.6789, 3.14159, 7890.0, 1230000.0, 3141000000.0]
```

This handles "K", "M" and "B", plus when there is no designation, plus whether there is leading and/or trailing whitespace.

This works because `v.to_f` ignores the non-digit characters for the multiplier:

```
'3.14159'.to_f # => 3.14159
'7.89K'.to_f # => 7.89
```

The rest of the question is left for you to figure out.