# ruby Compare values between hashes in different arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, compare

I have two different arrays, each consisting of different hashes.

```
new_array1 =    [
                    {:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC"},
                    {:index=>4, :column=>1, :ID=>"XYZ"},
                    {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547"}
                ]


new_array2 =    [
                    {:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC"},
                    {:index=>4, :column=>1, :ID=>"IJK"},
                    {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547"}
                ]
```

I want to compare the values of the `:ID` keys in `new_array1` vs the values in `new_array2` only if the `:index` and `:column` values are the same.

```
ie)   
if (new_array1[0][:index] == new_array2[0][:index]) and (new_array1[0][:column] == new_array2[0][:column])
   if(new_array1[0][:ID] == new_array2[0][:ID])
         # do something
   end
end
```

Is there a way to loop through all the hashes in both arrays and find the match? Or perhaps a more elegant way to do this in ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return an array of matching hashes:

```
res = new_array1.inject([]) { |memo, hash| memo << hash if new_array2.any? { |hash2| hash[:ID] == hash2[:ID] && hash[:index] == hash2[:index] && hash[:column] == hash2[:column] }; memo } 
# => [{:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC"}, {:index=>4, :column=>1, :ID=>"XYZ"}, {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547"}]

res.each do |hash|
  # do something
end
```

If an item in `new_array1` has the same `index`, `column` and `ID` keys as any item in `new_array2` it will be included.

You could also simpify if these are the only keys in the hashes by using `==` to compare equality:

```
res = new_array1.inject([]) { |memo, hash| memo << hash if new_array2.any? { |hash2| hash == hash2 }; memo }
```

The `inject` method, aliased and also known as `reduce`, takes a collection and creates a new value from it, each time the block given to `inject` is called it is given the next element of the collection and the return value of the previous block (the first time the block is called it is given the seed value passed to `inject`). This allows you to build up a value similar to recursion.

There are some examples of `inject` here: [Need a simple explanation of the inject method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710501/need-a-simple-explanation-of-the-inject-method)

The `any?` method will return true as soon as the given block returns true for any of the given collection elements. If the block never returns true then `any?` returns false. So:

```
[0,0,0,1,0].any? { |num| num == 1 } # => true
[0,0,0,0,0].any? { |num| num == 1 } # => false
```

Comment: 1. consider using `each_with_object` and 2. how this helps to “`# do something`”?

Comment: @mudasobwa they can iterate over `res` to do something, I'll update the answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!!

Can you explain what `inject([ ])` and `any?` do

Comment: Thank you, I ran into another issue here, if you could take at look that would greatly appreciated 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868693/ruby-array-error-typeerror-cant-convert-symbol-into-integer

Answer (score 0):

```
[new_array1, new_array2].map do |a|
  a.group_by { |e| [e[:index], e[:column]] }
end.reduce do |f, l|
  f.merge(l) { |_, f, l| [f.first[:ID], l.first[:ID]] }
end
# => {
#     [ 4, 0 ] => [
#         [0] "ABC",
#         [1] "ABC"
#     ],
#     [ 4, 1 ] => [
#         [0] "XYZ",
#         [1] "IJK"
#     ],
#     [ 4, 2 ] => [
#         [0] "BCD-1547",
#         [1] "BCD-1547"
#     ]
# }
```

Put `do_something unless f.first[:ID] == l.first[:ID]` instead of `[f.first[:ID], l.first[:ID]]` in the last clause to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If all hashes have the same three keys and no other keys it's simply

```
new_array1 & new_array2
  #=> [{:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC"},
  #    {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547"}]
```

If the hashes may have other keys as well, you can write the following.

```
new_array1 = [{:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC",      :pet=>"cat"},
              {:index=>4, :column=>1, :ID=>"XYZ",      :bet=>"red"},
              {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547", :met=>"Betty"}]

new_array2 = [{:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC",      :tree=>"maple"},
              {:index=>4, :column=>1, :ID=>"IJK",      :colour=>"blue"},
              {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547", :car=>"beemer"}]

keys = [:index,:column,:ID]
h1 = new_array1.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g.select { |k,_| keys.include? k }] = g }
  #=> {{:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC"}=>
  #      {:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC", :pet=>"cat"},
  #    {:index=>4, :column=>1, :ID=>"XYZ"}=>
  #      {:index=>4, :column=>1, :ID=>"XYZ", :bet=>"red"},
  #    {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547"}=>
  #      {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547", :met=>"Betty"}}
h2 = new_array2.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g.select { |k,_| keys.include? k }] = g }
  #=> {{:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC"}=>
  #      {:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC", :tree=>"maple"},
  #    {:index=>4, :column=>1, :ID=>"IJK"}=>
  #      {:index=>4, :column=>1, :ID=>"IJK", :colour=>"blue"},
  #    {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547"}=>
  #      {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547", :car=>"beemer"}} 
(h1.keys & h2.keys).map { |k| [h1[k], h2[k]] }
  #=> [[{:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC", :pet=>"cat"},
  #     {:index=>4, :column=>0, :ID=>"ABC", :tree=>"maple"}],
  #    [{:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547", :met=>"Betty"},
  #     {:index=>4, :column=>2, :ID=>"BCD-1547", :car=>"beemer"}]]
```

Comment: Thank you Cary. But I am having trouble understanding what type of data structure `h1, h2`, and `(h1.keys & h2.keys).map { |k| [h1[k], h2[k]] }` is. It looks like h1 and h2 are hashes, whereas the 3rd one is an array of arrays. Can you verify this?

Comment: `h1` and `h2` are indeed hashes, whose keys are also hashes. `h1.keys` and `h2.keys` are therefore arrays of hashes and their intersection is an array of those hashes that are keys in both `h1` and `h2`.So what I've done is create a hash with the three keys of interest for each hash in `new_array1` and `new_array2`, and obtain their intersection, as I did in he case when all hashes have the same three keys and no others. The last step is then to use that intersection together with `h1` and `h2` to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, I ran into another issue here, if you could take at look that would greatly appreciated 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868693/ruby-array-error-typeerror-cant-convert-symbol-into-integer

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow.