# Splitting an integer in an array into individual digits in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to gather input from the user, store that input as integers in an array, and then iterate over **every other** number, starting from second to last,and then taking those digits and multiply them by 2. After that, I sum the individual digits of the products, but I'm having trouble storing the result of that math as an integer

Here's my code:

```
# Prompt user for input

print "Number: "
array = []
card = gets.to_i
array << card


# Prompt the user until the number is valid

until card.is_a?(Integer) && card.positive? && card.to_s.length > 10
  print "Retry: "
  card = gets.to_i
  array << card
end

array = array.to_s.scan(/\d/).map(&:to_i) # split number in array by digit


i = -2 # starting the loop at second to last digit
t = ((array.length)/2).ceil # number of times to iterate through the array length & roundup
$sum = 0

t.times do #go through the array as many times as digits needed, starting 2nd to last
  $sum += ((array[i]) * 2).digits
  i -= 2
end

puts $sum
```

This gave me the console error:

```
Array can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
```

I also tried taking the individual digits of the product and putting them into a new array like this

```
final_array = []

t.times do #go through the array as many times as digits needed, starting 2nd to last
  final_array << ((array[i]) * 2).digits.to_i
  i -= 2
end
```

But this gave me the error `undefined method to_i for [2]:Array`

I know that there is another way to solve this problem using %, but I'm trying to do it with an array. Hope someone can help!

Comment: try using this : `final_array += ((array[i]) * 2).digits`

Comment: @OthmaneElKesri thank you so much, that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
final_array << ((array[i]) * 2).digits.to_i
```

By this one:

```
final_array += ((array[i]) * 2).digits
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with iterators and array slices.

Start by taking the array leaving off the last (-1) element with a slice ([ruby array slice method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice)), then reverse that slice.

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5]
 b = a.reverse[1..-1]
  => [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Next you want just even indexed elements of the new array, you can find that by iterating over the array and checking if it's index is even. The `each_with_index` method will help you with this ([Ruby enumerable each_with_index method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)). If the index is even, store the value at that index in another array

```
 c = []
 b.each_with_index {|n,i| c << n if i.even? }
 c
  => [4, 2]
```

Then use the array `inject` method to carry out the maths (well explained here - [SO discussion of Ruby inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710501/need-a-simple-explanation-of-the-inject-method)).

```
 c.inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + (n * 2) }
  => 12
```

This approach allows you to skip messing with counter variables and working backwards over arrays and just stick to Ruby iterators.