# How can I modify content of an array in one loop

Tags: ruby

I have an array that looks like this:

```
strings= ['','','','   Some text', '', '     Some another text']
```

how can I map striped text only?
right now I am doing this:

```
strings.select!{|string| !string.emtpy?}
strings.map!{|string| string.strip}
```

as you can see there are 2 loops. which I think is not efficient

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `lazy` not to create an intermediate array for every step.
It is still 2 iterations, but memory efficient, yet readable

```
strings.lazy.select {|string| !string.empty? }.map {|string| string.strip }.to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` here:

```
strings.grep(/.+/, &:strip)
 #=> ["Some text", "Some another text"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 `strings.map {|string| string.strip if string.strip.size > 0}`.compact

> ["Some text", "Some another text"]
```

Explanation:

```
strings.map {|string| string.strip if string.strip.size > 0}
```

It will return:

```
> [nil, nil, nil, "Some text", nil, "Some another text"]
```

nil in case when string is empty. Else it will return stripped text.

.compact: Returns a copy of self with all nil elements removed.

So, `[nil, nil, nil, "Some text", nil, "Some another text"].compact` 
will be:`> ["Some text", "Some another text"]`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Aurril I edited and explained above in short. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve that with `#inject` ([SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/710514/2945616), [Ruby doc link](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)) with one loop:

```
strings.inject([]) { |arr, val| val.present? ? arr.push(val.strip) : arr }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not most memory efficient (because you create another array)  buy will do the job in one loop (There may be shorter ways to write this code. I am also using `text!=''` instead `emtpy?`because I do not use Rails

```
strings = ['','','','   Some text', '', '     Some another text']
stripped_strings = []
strings.each do |text|
if !(text=='')
   stripped_strings << text.strip
end
puts stripped_strings
```

Output will be ['Some text','Some another text']

The next way works for me in Ruby 2.1.7 I am not sure it will work in other versions. And I think it is a little risky. But you will not need an extra Array

```
strings = ['','','','   Some text', '', '     Some another text']
strings.select! do |text|
    text.strip!
    text != ''
end
```

This works because that Ruby treats the String as an Object. Tell me comment If you want more explanation on this

A third option is also a little risky would be to delete the elements from the array while iterating on it. For this I am not using `string.each` because removing items from array while running the each can be problematic also. Now I do not need to worry whether the each is cloning the the `|text|` (then the strip! will not change the original array like in previous example)

```
strings = ['','','','   Some text', '', '     Some another text']
$i = strings.length - 1
while $i >= 0 do
  if strings[$i] == ''
    strings.delete_at($i)
  else
    strings[$i].strip!
  end
  $i -= 1
end
puts strings
```