# Sum up the total of a field in ActiveRecord using inject in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Help me understand this ActiveRecord error, and also please tell me the right way to write this.

I have a Payment model

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord

  enum status: %w(success, failed, initialized)

  scope :successful, -> { where(status: :success) }

  def self.find_total_amount_spent(user_id)
    total_amount = 0
    total_amount = self.where(user_id: user_id, status: :success).inject(0) {|amount, payment| amount + payment.amount }
    return total_amount/100.0
  end
end
```

In the `find_total_amount_spent` method, I want to get the total amount a user has spent.

But I get this error

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "success"
SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."user_id" = $1 AND "payments"."status" = $2):`

My understanding of this error is that I'm not supposed to pass in the `:success` symbol? 
But I've used it in other parts of my app where it worked. More so it is used in the [enum doc as well](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Is it that inject expects every value passed to it to be an integer? Yes, that's what I thought based on my understanding of inject [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/710514/5012862)

So if inject is not the right method to use here, could you please explain to me a better approach and better way to arrive at a solution?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `inject` method. It's about your enum definition.

This

```
%w(success, failed, initialized)
```

is evaluated to

```
["success,", "failed,", "initialized"]
```

Get rid of those commas :)

```
enum status: %w(success failed initialized)
```

Anyway, using SQL would be way better

```
def self.find_total_amount_spent(user_id)
  (successful.where(user_id: user_id).sum(:amount) || 0) / 100.0
end
```

Comment: That is one mistake. Another thing to fix if  you are not in Rails 5 is that, you need pass the actual integer. Like `self.where(user_id: user_id, status: self.statuses['success']` .. Because that is what the SQL query errors out. The actual column is integer, but you pass it the string.

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel so stupid. Given that I know about this even before now.

It's okay I'm in Rails 5 and it works now, the error is gone now. Another question I have is, is this the best way to sum up these values? what happens when a user has 100s of this payment records? 

Could it be better written with reduce(:+) ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way better way: use SQL. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @mayorsanmayor `self.where(user_id: user_id, status: :success).sum(:amout) / 100`

Comment: Thank you @Ursus and Thank you very much @Arup. I really appreciate your time. 

Yes! it worked. Here's the interpreted query from server log - `SELECT SUM("payments"."amount") FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."status" = $1 AND "payments"."user_id" = $2  [["status", 0], ["user_id", 106]]`

Thank you again.